# What is the difference between "Autocomplete" and "Autocomplete (Tags style)" field widget type?

Tags: 7, entities, ajax

What is the difference between an "autocomplete" and an "autocomplete (Tags style)" widget. These options are present when I add an entity reference field for example.

Comment: While using entity reference I asked this question and found that: https://www.drupal.org/node/241255

Comment: @herci Sorry but I don't see how this link is relevant. Are you sure you pasted what you meant to paste?

Comment: @Mołot you're right. :) The "7" was gone away from end of the link. Correct one is that: https://www.drupal.org/node/2412557

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For one term, there is no difference.

When you increase cardinality (i.e. allow unlimited number of values), with tag style you will put all tags in one textbox, just like you do with tags on this site, and with regular autocomplete you will need to put each one with it's own textbox.

Comment: Vote up, good memory  Molot :D

Comment: @zhilevan thanks. Removed part about my bad memory ;) as it seems it's not needed.

Comment: Your welcome my friend, yes remove it ;) :D